# updating dataframe in R based on another dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

**EDIT**

I have a dataframe `t`.

```
> t
       v     w  e
1   dave  adam ->
2 floria  adam ->
3 floria  dave ->
4 floria quinn ->
5  quinn  adam ->
```

and another dataframe `data`.

```
> data
      v      w   e
1  dave floria  ->
2 quinn   adam <->
```

I want to update the column e in dataframe `t` based on dataframe `data`.

There can be cases where the v and w in `t` are the same as the v and w in `data` but are swapped. This is the case for dave and floria. In `t`, dave is in w and floria is in v; while in `data`, dave is in v and floria is in w. As long as the names are in v and w in any order i want to change e.

**My expected output is:**

```
       v     w   e
1   dave  adam  ->
2 floria  adam  ->
3 floria  dave  <-
4 floria quinn  ->
5  quinn  adam <->
```

The the first row of `data` data-frame shows Dave -> Floria and the second row shows Quinn <-> Adam. This is why in the expected output, in row 3 the arrow points at floria and in row 5 the arrow is bidirectional.

How exactly can I do this in dplyr?

Comment: I don't understand your expected output (I really doesn't help that you keep changing the output!). Why is the flag for ("quinn", "adam") TRUE and why does `e` become "<->"? If I look at `t` as a graph, there is no path from "adam" to "quinn". There are however multiple paths from "floria" to "adam": (1) floria -> adam; (2) floria -> quinn -> adam; (3) floria -> dave -> adam. Originally you had only one `data.frame`; now you introduce two `data.frame`s, where `data` seems (to some degree) redundant?

Comment: Does the EDIT make sense? I tried to make it simpler. The the first row of  `data` dataframe shows Dave -> Floria and the second row shows Quinn <-> Adam. Which is why the expected output in row 3 the arrow points at floria and in row 5 the arrow is bidirectional

Comment: I just updated my whole question in attempt to be less confusing. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm still confused about the output. For example: `t` has "floria" -> "dave", and `data` has "dave" -> "floria". Why does this not become "floria" <-> "dave"? Instead you have "flora" <- "dave"?

Comment: `t` is the original dataframe, we want to change the column e from `t` based on `data`. For example in row 1 of `data` the names are dave and floria which matches with row 3 of `t`. The original direction in `t` is Floria -> Dave but we need to change it to Dave -> Floria (based on `data`).

Answer (score 0):

You may try using `intersect`

```
t %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(flag = (v %in% V & w %in% W) & (match(w,W) == match(v,V)) | (v %in% W & w %in% V) & (match(w,V) == match(v,W)),
              txt = ifelse(flag, paste(intersect(v,c(V,W)),E,intersect(w,c(V,W))), paste(v,e,w)))

  v      w     e     flag  txt            
  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <lgl> <chr>          
1 dave   adam  ->    FALSE dave -> adam   
2 floria adam  ->    FALSE floria -> adam 
3 floria dave  ->    TRUE  floria <-> dave
4 floria quinn ->    FALSE floria -> quinn
5 quinn  adam  ->    TRUE  quinn <-> adam
```

## Edit

```
t <- read.table(text = "       v     w  e
   dave  adam '<-'
 floria  adam '->'
 floria  dave '<-'
 floria quinn '->'
  quinn  adam '->' ", header = T)
t

       v     w  e
1   dave  adam <-
2 floria  adam ->
3 floria  dave <-
4 floria quinn ->
5  quinn  adam ->

V <- c('dave', 'quinn')
W <- c('floria', 'adam')
E <- c('<-', '<->')
t %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(flag = (v %in% V & w %in% W) & (match(w,W) == match(v,V)) | (v %in% W & w %in% V) & (match(w,V) == match(v,W)),
         txt = case_when(
           flag & (e %in% E) ~ paste(intersect(v,c(V,W)),intersect(E,e),intersect(w,c(V,W))),
           flag ~ paste(intersect(v,c(V,W)),"<->",intersect(w,c(V,W))),
           TRUE ~ paste(v,e,w)
         ))

  v      w     e     flag  txt            
  <chr>  <chr> <chr> <lgl> <chr>          
1 dave   adam  <-    FALSE dave <- adam   
2 floria adam  ->    FALSE floria -> adam 
3 floria dave  <-    TRUE  floria <- dave 
4 floria quinn ->    FALSE floria -> quinn
5 quinn  adam  ->    TRUE  quinn <-> adam
```

## Edit 2

It's bit a mess but you may try.

```
t %>%
  rowwise %>%
  mutate(key = paste0(v,w),
         #key2 = paste0(w,v),
         key1 = match(key, data2$key1),
         key2 = match(key, data2$key2)
         ) %>%
  mutate(e = case_when(
    is.na(key1) & is.na(key2) ~ e,
    !is.na(key1) & data2$e[key1] == "<->" ~ "<->",
    !is.na(key1) & data2$e[key1] == "->" ~ "->",
    !is.na(key1) & data2$e[key1] == "<-" ~ "<-",
    data2$e[key2] == "<->" ~ "<->",
    data2$e[key2] == "->" ~ "<-",
    data2$e[key2] == "<-" ~ "<->",
    TRUE ~ e
  )) %>%
  select(-key, -key1, -key2)

  v      w     e    
  <chr>  <chr> <chr>
1 dave   adam  ->   
2 floria adam  ->   
3 floria dave  <-   
4 floria quinn ->   
5 quinn  adam  <->
```

Comment: Thanks! but What if `E <- c('<-', '<->')` (i.e. they're not the same value?) The way your code is written won't account for it

Comment: @bananaboy Is there conditions for `E`?

Comment: E is the direction of the change. Each index of E corresponds to the index of V and W.  So If I have `V <- c('dave', 'quinn')`, `W <- c('floria', 'adam')`, and `E <- c('<-', '<->')`, for the 1st index I would want to have the `txt` column be Dave <- Floria.

Comment: @bananaboy I add the code above, but it's hard for me to understand condition.

Comment: Sorry I updated my question to add a slightly different interpretation. Let me know if you can help.

Comment: @bananaboy I think I can help you just a little bit later......About an hour....I'm really sorry.

Comment: Thanks, I just updated my question in hopes to be less confusing..

Comment: @bananaboy I add the code above. Please check it out.